# Inline tag editing doesn't change info about last editing without page refreshing

Tags: bug, tags, inline-tag-editor

Inline tag editing doesn't change info about last editing. Only after the page refreshing the change becomes visible.

> [image]

Is it a bug, or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?